# TypeError: Cannot read property 'buildMeta' of undefined

Tags: webpack

On webpack@5.72.0 (currently the latest), I started seeing:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'buildMeta' of undefined
    at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency._getEffectiveExportPresenceLevel (/src/project/node_modules/.pnpm/webpack@5.72.0_webpack-cli@4.9.2/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:165:43)
    at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.getWarnings (/src/project/node_modules/.pnpm/webpack@5.72.0_webpack-cli@4.9.2/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:176:32)
    at Compilation.reportDependencyErrorsAndWarnings (/src/project/node_modules/.pnpm/webpack@5.72.0_webpack-cli@4.9.2/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:3132:24)
    at /src/project/node_modules/.pnpm/webpack@5.72.0_webpack-cli@4.9.2/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:2729:28
```

The top frame is ([source code here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blame/86a8bd9618c4677e94612ff7cbdf69affeba1268/lib/dependencies/HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js#L162)):

```
  /**
   * @param {ModuleGraph} moduleGraph module graph
   * @returns {number} effective mode
   */
  _getEffectiveExportPresenceLevel(moduleGraph) {
    if (this.exportPresenceMode !== ExportPresenceModes.AUTO)
      return this.exportPresenceMode;
    return moduleGraph.getParentModule(this).buildMeta.strictHarmonyModule
      ? ExportPresenceModes.ERROR
      : ExportPresenceModes.WARN;
  }
```

Why would `moduleGraph.getParentModule(this)` be undefined? What should normally prevent it?

I dumped out `this` from inside `_getEffectiveExportPresenceLevel` and got:

```
HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency {
  _parentModule: undefined,
  _parentDependenciesBlock: undefined,
  _parentDependenciesBlockIndex: -1,
  weak: false,
  optional: false,
  _locSL: 1,
  _locSC: 12241,
  _locEL: 1,
  _locEC: 12242,
  _locI: undefined,
  _locN: undefined,
  _loc: SourceLocation {
    start: Position { line: 1, column: 12241 },
    end: Position { line: 1, column: 12242 }
  },
  request: '@emotion/stylis',
  userRequest: '@emotion/stylis',
  range: [ 12241, 12242 ],
  assertions: undefined,
  sourceOrder: 4,
  ids: [ 'default' ],
  name: 'p',
  exportPresenceMode: 2,
  namespaceObjectAsContext: false,
  call: undefined,
  directImport: true,
  shorthand: false,
  asiSafe: true,
  usedByExports: undefined
}
```

I'm not too sure what this means. Maybe `request` or `userRequest` are a hint (`@emotion/stylis`). I'm not sure if the problem is more on the importing side than the imported and which one this is referring to.

Not sure why this suddenly started happening, suppose some change in package versions. Code and config unchanged lately in that area of the project.

Answer (score 15):

For me, I have changed some properties of package.json file from

```
"webpack": "5.71.0",
"webpack-cli": "4.9.2",
"webpack-dev-server": "4.8.0"
```

to

```
"webpack": "5.65.0",
"webpack-cli": "4.9.1",
"webpack-dev-server": "4.7.1",
```

Comment: +1 I also fixed this by modifying my versions.  But in my case by going to latest.  clean-webpack-plugin@3.0.0
copy-webpack-plugin@6.4.1
webpack-bundle-tracker@1.6.0
webpack-cli@4.10.0
webpack-dev-server@4.11.1
webpack@5.74.0  So **something** happened in one of those releases that broke the compilation under some condition and either going back to last stable or up to latest fixed solved it for me.

Comment: Using news versions of all of these packages solved the issue for me

Comment: For me it worked by switching to the versions above from
```
        "webpack": "5.74.0",
        "webpack-cli": "4.10.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "4.10.1"
```

Answer (score 4):

The project yielding this issue was a pnpm-based monorepo with internal package dependencies using webpack build caches. I found unifying the webpack version throughout the monorepo resolved the issue.

Comment: This fixed it for me: for big repos the package `yarn-deduplicate` may prove useful for this